# CUDA dynamic parallelism in a GPU with compute capability 3.0

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to have **Dynamic Parallelism** feature in devices with compute capability less than ***3.5***?
I know that *nvcc* will return an error if it encounter a kernel launch in a kernel, but is it possible to declare some PTX-level function to support this feature?
For example here I have declared `cudaLaunchDevice()`:

```
.extern .func(.param .b32 func_retval0) cudaLaunchDevice
{
    .param .b32 fun,
    .param .b32 parameterBuffer,
    .param .align 4 .b8 gridDimension[12],
    .param .align 4 .b8 blockDimension[12],
    .param .b32 sharedMemSize,
    .param .b32 stream
}
```

To hope that the CUDA-level declaration of this function in `cuda_device_runtime_api.h` will be mapped to the previous PTX-level declaration. (Does the program have to be linked with something?)

```
//CUDA-level declaration of cudaLaunchDevice()
extern "C" __device__
cudaError_t cudaLaunchDevice(void *func, void *parameterBuffer,
                             dim3 gridDimension, dim3 blockDimension,
                             unsigned int sharedMemSize,
                             cudaStream_t stream);
```

(The codes are from **CUDA C programming guide** book *v6.5*)
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that does not work. You'll have to have a Kepler GK110 or any first or second generation Maxwell card.

"Dynamic Parallelism is only supported by devices of compute capability 3.5 and higher."
Source: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ixzz3OB61zgmK